# Figure out if Entity Framework Model Changed during DbContext Construction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

Is it possible to detect whether the underlying model changed during the construction of the Entity Framework DbContext?

The reason is that I'm attaching a `ObjectMaterialized` event handler during DbContext construction, but this fails with an `InvalidOperationException` (underlying model has changed) if the model has changed, so I'd like to conditionalize that event handler attachment only if the model has **not** changed.

Comment: Try `if (context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true)) { ... }` https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/prevent-ef-migrations-from-creating-or-changing-the-database/

Comment: Thanks, @SteveGreene - this solved this.

Answer (score 0):

you can Try ChangeTracker

```
public bool ISContextChanges()
```

{

```
return this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(a => a.State == EntityState.Added
                                          || a.State == EntityState.Modified
                                          || a.State == EntityState.Deleted);
```

}

Comment: That will check if the data changed, not the schema (model).